# MochaUI won't load script src in window

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to load a page into a modal window. I'd prefer to load with it the necessary js files rather than call them in the `head` where they will be loaded for every page including the ones they aren't needed on.

The problem is I can't get the scripts to load. It seems like something is preventing them from working. I've set `evalScripts` to false and changed the loadMethod to xhr as the docs say the evalScripts option is an option of xhr. Note: it didn't work before I changed to xhr and evalScripts: false.

Here is the call:

```
MUI.newthingWindow = function() {
    new MUI.Modal({
        id: 'newthing',
        title: 'New Thing',         
        contentURL: '/things/newThing/1',
        type: 'modal',
        loadMethod: 'xhr',
        evalScripts: false,
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        padding: { top: 43, right: 12, bottom: 10, left: 12 },
        scrollbars: false
    });
};
if ($('newThingLink')) {
    $('newThingLink').addEvent('click', function(e){
        new Event(e).stop();
        MUI.newthingWindow();
    });
}
```

Any clues?

Tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
evalScripts: false,
```

needs to be

```
evalScripts: true,
```

to allow scripts on the page to work, but still no dice on loading external scripts via `script src`. Though, this will allow for a js loader (using jQuery btw "jq").

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jq.getScript('/assets/js/things/new_thing.js', function(data, textStatus){
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log('Load was performed.');
});
</script>
```